# Как получить размер вложенного объекта в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

База имеет вид:

```
{
    "ФИО" : "Петров Петр Петрович",
    "Контакты" : {
        "Телефон" : "+79163054559",
        "Skype" : "petro"
    }
}
{
    "ФИО" : "Иванов Иван Иванович",
    "Контакты" : {
        "Телефон" : "+79039058549",
        "Skype" : "Ivanych",
        "telegram" : "@III"
    }
}
```

Нужно получить количество контактов для каждого пользователя, например:

```
Петров Петр Петрович - 2
Иванов Иван Иванович - 3
```

Никак не могу сообразить

Comment: `Object.keys(contacts).length` или `Object.values(contacts).filter((x) => x !== null && x !== undefined && /\S/.test(x)).length`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811379/count-fields-in-a-mongodb-collection